# How to rebase master and integrate [master] changes into my branch?

Tags: git

I have a local branch I'm working on that is a copy of master, called mybranch.  I have changes to that branch that I want to merge into master.  However, there have been updates to master that I need to incorporate into mybranch before I eventually merge my branch back into master.

I'd like to accomplish with a rebase and had somebody help me the first time but didn't really make sense.  I tried the following but I can remember say files that are different in mybranch and master highlighted in my intellij IDE as read with diffs in the file itself marked with >>>>HEAD, ETC,.  so I could update to the correct changes but I'm not seeing that.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$ git checkout master 
$ git pull  // get latest from master
$ git checkout mybranch
$ git rebase master     // get masters updates and integrate them with mine
```

At this point not sure where I'm at...I just want my local branch updated with masters changes (and there should be conflicts which I hope to resolve then push to my branch then push everything back to master).

Comment: This is ambiguous: `// get masters updates and integrate them with mine`.  You want the history to include the changes in master 'first' (i.e. older in time), and you want your latest changes to be written 'on top of' the newest stuff.  So, master is `A->B->X->Y` and mybranch is `A->B->K->L` and you want to end up at `A->B->X->Y->K'->L'`  (where `K'` and `L'` are your changes, perhaps with some tidyup from you.)

Comment: Your question's second paragraph is kinda confusing. Do you mean that you expected to have a conflict when rebasing and there was none? If so, wasn't simply the case that git have merged it gracefully?

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. Yes, I expect to have a a conflict with the pom. That is, Once I branch initially the pom is the same.  I update my pom in my branch then somebody updates the pom in master.  Now, I have other changes but want to rebase with master.  When I tried the rebase git didn't complain about the different versions of  the pom.  Since I wanted to pull in master's latest changes via a rebase I would expect it to update my pom.xml in intellij and ask me what changes I want to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common workflow you are describing. Here is a link to a [more detailed description](http://reinh.com/blog/2009/03/02/a-git-workflow-for-agile-teams.html).

Once you execute `'git rebase master'` you should have the latest changes from master in your current branch (you may or may not experience merge conflicts). If there are conflicts git will suspend the rebase and prompt you to resolve them, then execute '`git add <file(s)>`' before resuming the rebase with '`git rebase --continue`'.

While it's beyond the scope of you question I do recommend you check out the link or search around for information on interactive rebases. It's used to keep your commit history very clean and organized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I can't figure out is why I didn't get flagged for conflicts.  My pom.xml in mybranch is different than masters, yet when I did the rebase git didn't complain after the rebase?  Why is that?

Comment: That link is very helpful since I'm obviously a newbie.  =)

Comment: Difficult for me to say why exactly without putting eyes on it. Likely git was able to apply the change set to your branch without merge conflicts. A look at ``git diff master..`` might help.

Answer (score 1):

The above took the changes you had in mybranch above "old master" and applied them on top of "refreshed master" if you want to update master with your changes you are simply missing:

```
  git checkout master
  git rebase mybranch
```

which will fast forward master to the HEAD of your new (rebased on master) mybranch. Now master and mybranch should refer to the same SHA1 which are childs of origin/master. At this point, had you started to work on master after the updates from git pull, you would be in that same spot in the history tree.

```
  git push
```

should take care of breaking the daily build ;)